# How to make Emacs Gnus to get new mails automatically?

Tags: email, emacs, gnus

I try to fetch new mails with Gnus, but it doesn't work. I tried following options in my `.emacs` file:

```
;(setq gnus-demon-timestep 10)
(gnus-demon-add-handler 'gnus-group-get-new-news 1 nil)
;(gnus-demon-add-handler 'gnus-demon-scan-mail 1 nil)
;(gnus-demon-add-handler 'gnus-demon-scan-news 1 nil)
(gnus-demon-init)
```

I tried to add each of the 3 handlers, and put `t` instead of `nil`, but it didn't work. If I press `g` or run `M-x gnus-group-get-new-news` manually Gnus does fetchs new mails. I checked `gnus-demon-handlers` and it indeed says: `gnus-demon-handlers's value is ((gnus-group-get-new-news 1 nil))` but it doesn't fetch mails automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving (gnus-demon-init) above the rest. The functions don't exist until that the demon is initialized.

e.g.

```
(add-hook 'gnus-startup-hook
  '(lambda ()
     (gnus-demon-init)
     (setq gnus-demon-timestep 60)  ;; each timestep is 60 seconds
     ;; Check for new mail every 1 timestep (1 minute)
     (gnus-demon-add-handler 'gnus-demon-scan-news 1 t)

     ;; Don't crash gnus if disconnected
     (defadvice gnus-demon-scan-news (around gnus-demon-timeout activate)
       "Timeout for Gnus."
       (with-timeout
       (120 (message "Gnus timed out."))
     ad-do-it))))
```